# Autoit script not working

Tags: automation, autoit

I have an AutoIt script that works.
I need to update the script to open an application and to press some buttons in some windows.
The only thing that works is running the application: `RunWait(exe file)`.
When the application is running I need to click an OK button on the window that pops up and then click another button on the next windows but all of that is not working.

```
RunWait(exe file)
WinWaitActive("win title","",10)
ControlCommand("win title","",1,"check","")
```

This is the part that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of,
Dot use **RunWait()** , instead use **Run()**.
RunWait will wait until the application is closed.
Use AutoItWindowInfo tool in order to find the info on the control you want to manipulate.

Example:

```
ControlClick("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]")
```

Also use

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

This will make sure your script can see the child windows.